# Button not working on UIView with AutoLayout than working but view layout messed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

I have this UIView that located on top of the main view, I'm using AutoLayout and he is not responding. Than I read here that someone already had this issue and he fixed it by setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES, so I did that, and now the UIView is located not where I wanted it to be.

At first the view frame was 0, 0, 320, 44 (thats on the top of the view)

Now its on the bottom of the view.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout and UIButton Action don't have any relation.Please make sure your button is above the top view.It might be possible that your transparent top view overlapping the button.Make sure the user interaction of UIButton and its superview should be enable.